# laravel relationship eagerload mailable

Tags: laravel

I try to pass relationship datas to a mailable, but datas are not in the Mailable build.

**The Controller**

```
    public function send()
    {
        $domaines = $this->domaineRepository::domaineNewsletter("2022-05-23", "2022-05-30");
        
        $abonnes = Newsletter::where('name', 'MyNewsletter')->first()->users;

        foreach($abonnes as $abonne) {
            Mail::to($abonne->email)
                ->queue(
                    (new PortailNewsletter("title", "Some text", "2022-05-23", "2022-05-30", $domaines))
                        ->onQueue('portailNewsletter')
                    );
        }
    }
```

**The Mailable**

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use App\Repositories\Portail\DomaineRepository;

class PortailNewsletter extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $title;
    public $subtitle;
    public $date_begin;
    public $date_end;
    public $domaines;

    /**
     * The name of the theme that should be used when formatting the message.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    public $theme = "portailNewsletter";

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($title, $subtitle, $date_begin, $date_end, $domaines)
    {
        $this->title= $title;
        $this->subtitle= $subtitle;
        $this->date_begin= $date_begin;
        $this->date_end= $date_end;
        $this->domaines = $domaines;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from([
                        'address' => 'john.doe@mail.com',
                        'name' => 'John',
                    ])
                    ->subject($title)
                    ->markdown('portail.mail.newsletter');
    }
}
```

**The repository**

```
    public static function domaineNewsletter($date_begin, $date_end)
    {

        $callback = function ($query) use ($date_begin, $date_end) {
            $query->where('date_publication', '<=', $date_end)
                ->where('date_publication', '>=', $date_begin)
                ->orderBy('date_publication', 'desc');
        };

        return Domaine::query()->whereHas('actualite', $callback)
                        ->with(['actualite' => $callback])
                        ->get()
                        ;
    }
```

For the domaines datas :

- When i do a dd() in the repository, it's OK, i have the expected datas with relationship and eagerload.
- When i do a dd() in the send() function of the Controller, it's OK, i have the expected datas with relationship and eagerload.
- When i do a dd() in the __construct() function of the Mailable, it's OK, i have the expected datas with relationship and eagerload.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#705
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => App\Models\Portail\Domaine {#703
      #connection: "mysql_laravel"
      #table: "domaines"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:5 [
        "id" => 1
        "libelle_domaine" => "Domaine1"
        "created_at" => null
        "deleted_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
      ]
      #original: array:5 [
        "id" => 1
        "libelle_domaine" => "Domaine1"
        "created_at" => null
        "deleted_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: array:1 [
        "deleted_at" => "datetime"
      ]
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: array:1 [
        0 => "deleted_at"
      ]
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
======> #relations: array:1 [                   <====== relation OK, eagerload OK
        "actualite" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#690
          #items: array:1 [
            0 => App\Models\Portail\Actualite {#669
              #connection: "mysql_laravel"
              #table: "actualites"
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #withCount: []
              +preventsLazyLoading: false
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
              #attributes: array:14 [
                ...
              ]
              #original: array:14 [
                ...
              ]
              #changes: []
              #casts: array:1 [
                "deleted_at" => "datetime"
              ]
              #classCastCache: []
              #attributeCastCache: []
              #dates: array:1 [
                0 => "deleted_at"
              ]
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #dispatchesEvents: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: []
              #touches: []
              +timestamps: true
              #hidden: []
              #visible: []
              #fillable: []
              #guarded: array:1 [
                0 => "*"
              ]
              #forceDeleting: false
            }
          ]
          #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

- When i do a dd() in the build() function of the Mailable, **it's KO**, i have not the expected datas, i have not the relationship and eagerload.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#686
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => App\Models\Portail\Domaine {#685
      #connection: "mysql_laravel"
      #table: "domaines"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:5 [
        "id" => 1
        "libelle_domaine" => "Domaine1"
        "created_at" => null
        "deleted_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
      ]
      #original: array:5 [
        "id" => 1
        "libelle_domaine" => "Domaine1"
        "created_at" => null
        "deleted_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: array:1 [
        "deleted_at" => "datetime"
      ]
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: array:1 [
        0 => "deleted_at"
      ]
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
======> #relations: []                   <====== No relation, no eagerload
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

I've tried this in the mailable :

```
    public function build()
    {
        $test= DomaineRepository::domaineNewsletter("2022-05-23", "2022-05-30");
        dd($test);
}
```

It returns the expected datas with relationship and eagerload.

So, have you some idea why, in the mailable, $this->domaines from the __construct is not available with the eagerload in the build ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about queue, relationship and (de)serialization.

In Laravel doc : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#handling-relationships

```
Any previous relationship constraints that were applied before the model was serialized
during the job queueing process will not be applied when the job is deserialized.
Therefore, if you wish to work with a subset of a given relationship,
you should re-constrain that relationship within your queued job.
```

For me, i've

relationship in controller --> mail queue --> serialization --> job handle --> deserialization --> mailable build

the constrain's relationship must be re-constrain in the mailable build